# iOS disable let user swipe the app in background list

Tags: ios, background, task

In the iOS, when the user double home button , the app show in the list at background.

Have possible hidden my app show in the list, or force the user swiped the app, the app in the background can't close?

I just known applicationDidEnterBackground can do something in the background. But

I wish force the user can't swipe the app in the list or hidden the app in the list, or have some mobile device management method can do this effect(we can use private api)?

I search many time , but I was not found some answer...

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in iOS, the user is in control and Apple does not allow your app to hide it self in this list.

If you want this you will need to target jailbroke devices and hook on the task switch. Then detect you app from being closed and restarted it.